# List the file name and its specific date creation within different Folder or directories - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried to apply the below python codes, but it not getting the correct creation date.

```py
import os, pandas as pd, datetime

l = []
pt = r"C:\Users\ndofi.vontade\OneDrive - Jupiter Desenvolvimento Informatico LTDA\Documentos\Jupiter\BI"
count = 0
for dirpath, dirname, filename  in os.walk (pt):
    for file in filename:
        
        count = count + 1
        date_mod = os.path.getctime(pt)
        dt_m = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp (date_mod)
        #l.append( (os.path.join(dirpath, file)))
        print (count,file, dt_m)
```

Comment: i tried the same code and it looks fine....  maybe something to do with onedrive.

Comment: Thanks D.L! You are correct, the code is indeed working.